# Strange for loop in salsa20_word_specification function

Tags: stream-cipher, salsa20

This is wrt to implementation of the salsa20_word_specification function at https://cr.yp.to/salsa20.html

The 2nd for loop goes like this

```
 for (i = 20;i > 0;i -= 2) {
....
....
....
}
```

The value of `i` isn't used inside the for loop. So I am wondering why this loop starts with 20 & goes down to 0 decrementing 2 in each iteration?

The same thing could be done the regular way i.e.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
...
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think it is just the indication of this: "The entire series of modifications is a series of 10 identical double-rounds." It's right in the text above it. `i` counts the rounds. As a developer I'm more concerned that $i$ starts at 20, probably an obscure way of optimizing a check at 0 instead of 20...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - I don't understand - how does i count the rounds? for (i=0; i < 10; ++i) would count 10 rounds. Also how exactly is a check at 0 more optimized at compared to a check at 20?

Comment: It reads "**double-rounds**" right? So it performs 2 per iteration. As for comparison with zero, CPU's often carry a [zero flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_flag) which can be used within a branching instruction. Saves an explicit compare. It's a bit useless to program that in manually though as an optimizing compiler would be smart enough, and in that case counting from 10 would also be more optimized, but yeah....

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - there are 2 other for loops in the same function. Both of them use for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) - they could have been similarly written as for (i=16; i >0; --i) to use the same 0 optimization. I am wondering why this optimization is used only for one of the functions!

Comment: Dan and Tanja are heavily into optimization; the other for loops are basically copy procedures. No doubt a memory copy will go faster from low to high... In the end this is a *why* question, and we cannot look into the minds of the authors (we might hope that they see this anyway and want to give us a hint).